# ViewPager setOffscreenPageLimit not working when using it as NestedFragment with getChildFragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-nested-fragment

I am trying to do something similar as https://stackoverflow.com/a/24437224/2277631. I am even using the same layout:

[image]

I am following this approach because I am using a NavigationView (each option is a fragment) that has the first option as a fragment with Tabs (so a ViewPager with more fragments).

I found a problem when using:

`viewPager.setAdapter(new AdapterView(getChildFragmentManager()));`

Basically, using the ViewPager as nested fragment, it only loads 1 page (from the 3 tabs), and it only loads the other pages when I swipe to them (each tab is a fragment with its ContentLoader). I found that using `setOffscreenPageLimit`gets ignored in this case. Instead, if I use:
`getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` then the ViewPager works as expected (loading by default 1 page and the next and previous pages). But then, a lot of weird stuff happen (cause I am suppose to use `getChildFragmentManager` when using nested fragments). So... Any ideas of using ViewPager as nested fragment and make `setOffscreenPageLimit` to work?

**Edit 1 (30 Dec 15)**

Tracking the bug down, I checked that all the fragments are been created. The problem is that the three fragments have they own `LoaderCallback` but only the first one calls `onLoadFinished`. Trying to figure out why the other fragments only call `onLoadFinished` when navigating to it (was working without the nested approach).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. This is how I do and this is working for me, it has the same architetcure as what you expect to have.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.communitylayout, container, false);
        Bundle data = getArguments();

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.comtabs);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);


        // add tabs
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());

        RelativeLayout layout1 = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.communitytablayoutleft, container, false);
        RelativeLayout layout2 = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.communitytablayout, container, false);
        RelativeLayout layout3 = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.communitytablayoutright, container, false);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);



        pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.compager);
        CommunityPagerFragment adapter = new CommunityPagerFragment(getChildFragmentManager());

        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
        pager.setCurrentItem(0);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);

        // KEEP FRAGMENT STATE INSIDE OF THE TAB
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);


        ((TextView)layout1.findViewById(R.id.tabtext)).setText(tabs[0]);
        ((TextView)layout2.findViewById(R.id.tabtext)).setText(tabs[1]);
        ((TextView)layout3.findViewById(R.id.tabtext)).setText(tabs[2]);

        //tabLayout.set


        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(layout1);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(layout2);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(layout3);

        onTabSelected(tabLayout.getTabAt(1));
        //tabLayout.set

        return view;
```

And if you want to get the Tabs working by click in addition of the swipe, add the following:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}
```

Comment: Mmmm so you just recommend not to use nested fragments in this case? I have 3 fragments where I send a bundle and depending on those arguments they load something using a ContentLoader. I am not really sure your solution would help here. I think I won't use nested fragments, place the ViewPager in the main activity and hide/show it depending on the selected option :/